# How to run azure cli commands with serviceprinciple permissions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-cloud-shell

Been looking for a while but couldn't find the answer. I've been using service principle on my azure devops to modify my azure infrastructure via piplines (proper permissions). I need to run some of the commands locally using powershell, for example delete some of my azure roles.

Is there a way to use my service principle's permissions via cli / powershell to achieve what I'm looking for? Cannot do it via Connect-Azure as my user account's role has insufficient permissions. I need to do it with service principle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can login to the Azure CLI with a Service Principal.

To sign in with a service principal, you need:

- The URL or name associated with the service principal
- The service principal password, or the X509 certificate used to create the service principal in PEM format
- The tenant associated with the service principal, as either an `.onmicrosoft.com` domain or Azure object ID

`az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#sign-in-with-a-service-principal